# Understanding Grails mockFor demand

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm trying to write a unit test for my filters, and I'm struggling to understand the **demand** for my mocked object. Here is a simple failing test:

```
void "test my sanity"() {
    setup:
    def vendorPayment = mockFor(Payment)
    vendorPayment.demand.buyerId { -> 123}

    def vp = vendorPayment.createMock()
    //vp.buyerId=123
    println "buyer id: ${vp.buyerId}"

    when:
      def a = "testing"

    then:
      vp.buyerId == 123
}
```

I wanted to mock the getter for buyerId. Using demand doesn't work, but if I create the mock and then set the buyer id (the commented line), the test will pass. Does demand not work with getters? Is it because the getter is implicitly/dynamically created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `getBuyerId` has to be mocked. Groovy adds the accessor methods for you in compile time, so method on demand has to be mocked. Take this simple case:

```
class Payment {
    Integer buyerId
}
```

Getter/Setter for `Payment.groovy` will be added when the class is converted to bytecode after compile. Corresponding test would look like:

```
void "test my power"() {
    setup:
        def vendorPayment = mockFor(Payment)
        vendorPayment.demand.getBuyerId(1..2) { -> 123}

        def vp = vendorPayment.createMock()
        println "buyer id: ${vp.buyerId}"

    expect:
        vp.buyerId == 123

        //This would fail for < 2.3.* because of this bug which is fixed in 2.4
        //http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11075
        vendorPayment.verify() //null

}
```

Note the changes that was made:

- `getBuyerId` method is mocked instead of the field `buyerId`
- test demands that getBuyerId will be called 1 to 2 times (first while printing, second in then block). By default if nothing is specified, it assumes the method will be called once, which would fail in this case as `getBuyerId` is invoked twice.
- We can also verify that the mock control did its job after the test is done

Comment: Does this mean my mock control failed? Condition not satisfied:
vendorPayment.verify()
|             |
|             null

Comment: No. [This is a bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11075) which is fixed in 2.4.

Comment: Good to know. We are using 2.3.7. Thank you!